# Как повернуть подпись оси LineChart JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой нужно повернуть подпись вертикальной оси, чтобы имя отображалось не вертикально, а горизонтально, как это можно реализовать?

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.chart.LineChart;
import javafx.scene.chart.NumberAxis;
import javafx.scene.chart.XYChart;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series<Number,Number> series2 = new XYChart.Series<>();

        NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

        xAxis.setLabel("X");
        yAxis.setLabel("Y");

        LineChart<Number,Number> chart = 
            new LineChart<Number, Number>(xAxis, yAxis);

        chart.getData().add(series1);
        chart.getData().add(series2);

        double[] xs = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
        double[] ys = {0.5, 1.3, 2.4, 5.6, 8.8, 9.1};

        for (int i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(xs[i], ys[i]));
        }
        for (double x = 0; x <= 5.0; x += 1.5) {
            double y = x+2;
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<>(x,y));
        }

        Scene scene = new Scene( chart );

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.sizeToScene();
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Придётся переопределять. А что будет, если название вашего `yAxis` будет длинным?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста скинуть пример переопределения для NumberAxis, не представляю с чего начать.